# Remove all characters from a string except numbers and commas?

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I made a script in autohotkey to select everything (web page, document etc.), copy it, and append it onto the clipboard (not overwrite, add to what was already on it). From here I have been manually sorting through the content and typing the numbers from the clipboard into a spreadsheet.

I thought I would tweak the script a little so I can easy paste straight into my spreadsheet. However, due to my limited knowledge of AHC and regex I have has little luck in this endeavor.

The ultimate goal to copy something like the following:

> This is a sample 123,456,789 text to 654,321 get the point across. 123

and copy the following to the clipboard -- along with a newline at the end.

> 123456789 654321 123

Any and all help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In the title you say "remove everything except numbers and commas", but in the example given the commas are not present. Can you explain it a little more, please?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using several simple regexps in sequence:

1. replace all non-number characters between numbers with a space: `[^,\d]+` to `" "`
2. strip the commas inside numbers: `","` to `""`
3. trim the spaces at the beginning/end: `^\s*(\S.*\S|\S)\s*$` to `$1`

---

```
s := regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(s
                  , "[^,\d]+", " ")
                  , ",", "")
                  , "^\s*(\S.*\S|\S)\s*$", "$1")
```

To add a newline type  `` "`n" `` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following solution (high readabilty, only one simple RegEx, easy to customize):

1. Match all numbers with RegExMatch
2. Remove the ,
3. Concenate to a string
4. Trim to remove the last blank and append newline character

---

```
str := "This is a sample 123,456,789 text to 654,321 get the point across. 123"

Pos := 1
While (Pos := RegExMatch(str, "([\d,]+)", M, Pos + StrLen(M)))
{
    StringReplace, M1, M1, ",", ""

result .= M1 . " "
}

result = %result%
result .= "`n"
```